# Why Postgres doesn't return a result?

Tags: postgresql

My first function consumes an array of UUID and returns a set of rows from the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun1 (
  "UUID_" uuid []
)
RETURNS SETOF service AS
$body$
with recursive tree as (
 SELECT * FROM service 
  WHERE id = ANY($1) 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT service.* FROM service
      JOIN tree ON service.id = tree.parent_id)
 select distinct * from tree;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100 ROWS 1000;
```

For now I want to write another one to consume list of UUID as varchar and return the same data as the first function.

My bad try :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun2 (
  "UUID_" varchar
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  "ID" uuid,
  "NAME" varchar,
  "PARENT_ID" uuid
) AS
$body$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY  
with recursive tree as (
 SELECT * FROM service 
  WHERE id = ANY(string_to_array($1, ',')::UUID[]) 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT service.* FROM service
      JOIN tree ON service.id = tree.parent_id)

     select distinct(ID), name, parent_id from tree;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100 ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and show what you expect and what you get.

Comment: fun1  procedure  works fine and produce correct result. 
fun2 produces blank result without any fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer by myself :

function fun1 can use varchar with converting to array of UUID when I use it.
so I can write :

```
select * from fun1('{some UUID array as varchar}'::UUID[]);
```